# PostgreSQL does not drop partition cascade

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I have a DB with 2 partitioned tables like

```
create table ppp (
    id serial not null,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
);

insert into ppp (name) values ('ppp_first');
insert into ppp (name) values ('ppp_second');

create table rrr (
    id serial not null,
    ppp_id integer not null,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key (id, ppp_id),
    foreign key (ppp_id) references ppp (id) on delete cascade    
) partition by list(ppp_id);

create table rrr1 partition of rrr for values in (1);
create table rrr2 partition of rrr for values in (2);

create table sss (
    id bigserial not null,
    ppp_id integer not null,
    rrr_id integer not null,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key (id, ppp_id),
    foreign key (ppp_id, rrr_id) references rrr (ppp_id, id) on delete cascade
) partition by list(ppp_id);

create table sss1 partition of sss for values in (1);
create table sss2 partition of sss for values in (2);

insert into rrr (ppp_id, name) values (1, 'rrr_first');
insert into rrr (ppp_id, name) values (2, 'rrr_second');

insert into sss (ppp_id, rrr_id, name) values (1, 1, 'sss_first');
insert into sss (ppp_id, rrr_id, name) values (2, 2, 'sss_second');
```

I want to drop rrr1 with `drop table rrr1 cascade;`. It's dropped without errors but partition sss1 not dropped. So

```
=> select * from rrr;
 id | ppp_id |    name    
----+--------+------------
  2 |      2 | rrr_second
(1 row)

=> select * from sss;
 id | ppp_id | rrr_id |    name    
----+--------+--------+------------
  1 |      1 |      1 | sss_first
  2 |      2 |      2 | sss_second
```

Why sss1 not dropped by cascade? Request to drop without cascade leads to error.

Comment: `drop table ... cascade` drops the foreign key _constraint_ not the referenced table. That has nothing to do with partitioning

Comment: Why was not deleted row  "sss_first"?

Comment: Because `drop table ... cascade` only drops the **constraint**, not the referenced table or any referenced row